# "Special Theme" or "Special Issue"?

Tags: word-request

On the cover of a scientific journal on Tourism management Studies I like to say this volume is of articles about a particular subject say "IT and Tourism".
How should I put it?

> Tourism Management Studies
>
> Special Issue: Tourism and Information Technology

Answer (score 2):

Use issue. Issue would be the proper way to address the articles.

In this case the theme would be IT or Tourism

The issue is how IT impacts tourism